# Are the quantifiers interchangeable?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

In other words, is it true that $\forall x \; \exists y\;\phi(x, y) \iff \exists y\;\forall x \; \phi(x, y) $?

Comment: No, in general, quantifiers are not interchangeable. Plenty of counterexamples. Try googling.

Comment: **NO** : For any natural number $x$ there exists a natural number $y$ such that $x < y$, but it is **not** true that there exists a natural number $y$ such that $x < y$, for any natural number $x$.

Comment: It's one thing to give a counter-example, but it is quite another to understand the formal rules/axioms that will not allow us to infer $\forall x \; \exists y\;\phi(x, y) \implies \exists y\;\forall x \; \phi(x, y) $. I found it to be  the most difficult notion to formalize in my own proof-checking software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every child has a father, but there is not a father for all children.

Comment: [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_with_the_most_children)

Comment: Is it true that a mother can have many children but many mothers can't have a single child (i.e. same child)?

Comment: The Bible would say otherwise.  (This is a joke, ok?)

Answer (score 1):

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \exists y\in\mathbb{R}\,[x>y]$ is true, but $\exists y\in\mathbb{R}\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\,[x>y]$ is false.